# GraphQL: how can I throw a warning after a successful mutation?

Tags: graphql, apollo

Let's imagine I have a `createPost` mutation that inserts a new post. In a typical app, that mutation can either:

- Succeed, returning a `Post`.
- Fail, throwing an error (I use [apollo-errors](https://github.com/thebigredgeek/apollo-errors) to handle this).

What I'd like to implement is a middle scenario, where the mutation succeeds (returning a `Post`); but *also* somehow returns a warning to the user (e.g. `Your post is similar to post XYZ` or similar).

What would be a good GraphQL pattern to implement this? Adding a `warning` field to the `Post` type seems a little weird, but then again I'm not sure how to return both a `Post` and a `Warning` in the same mutation? Any ideas?

(Note that I'm using this scenario as an example, I'm interested in the general pattern of returning extra post-mutation data, not finding similar posts specifically)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All my mutations return a wrapping payload type rather than a single value type (e.g. `Post` in your case), I also don't ever throw in GraphQL unless it's a real system error -- if it's the consequence of user input or is an otherwise expected case, I model it into the return type.

Returning a wrapping payload is generally considered a best practice because a) your mutation should return entry points for *everything* in the graph that may have changed (not just the new post), and b) it gives you the easy ability to add new fields to the return type at a later time.

Remember, a mutation is essentially a function that takes in some input data and the current graph, and returns a new graph. It's generally a mistake to think in terms of REST-like CRUD operations.

```
type CreatePostError = {
    // Whatever you want
}

type CreatePostSuccess = {
    post: Post!
    warning: String
}

union CreatePostPayload = CreatePostSuccess | CreatePostError

mutation {
    // Other mutations
    createPost(/* args /*): CreatePostPayload
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and from asking around it does seem like the consensus best practice. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewIngram wouldn't this work so long as the warning is requested by the client. I found this post looking for a way to possibly return some warning messages such as soon to be deprecated features, etc.

Comment: GraphQL Rules is similar in that it recommends a [mutation payload](https://graphql-rules.com/rules/mutation-payload)