# How to collect and return warnings from services while processing GraphQL query?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

What is the best way to collect some specific property from all the leafs of the GraphQL graph, reducing it to some single array? For example, my service functions can "throw" some arbitrary string warnings which I want to collect and supply to the client besides the main data, e.g. expected output:

```
type EntityOutput {
  entity: Entity
  warnings: [String!]
}
```

Resolver:

```
@Mutation()
async updateEntity(
  @Args('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string,
  @Args('data') input: UpdateDto
): Promise<EntityOutputDto>
{
  return {
    entity: await this.service.update(id, input),
    warnings: []  // ???
  };
}
```

Service method:

```
async update(id: string, input: UpdateDto): Promise<Entity> {
  const entity = await this.repository.findOneOrFail(id, { relations: ['type'] });  // check existence

  if (Object.values(input).some(v => v !== undefined)) {
    const updateData: Partial<Entity & UpdateDto> = Object.assign({ id }, input);

    if (input.isCurrentEntityOfItsType === true) {
      await this.typesService.update(entity.type.id, { currentEntityId: id });  // <-- this also can create its own warnings
    } else if (input.isCurrentEntityOfItsType === false) {
      await this.typesService.update(entity.type.id, { currentEntityId: null as any });
    }

    await this.repository.save(updateData);
  } else {
    console.warn(`No properties to change were been provided`);  // <-- this is a warning I want to save
  }

  return this.findOne(id);
}
```

I think my question can be splitted into 2:

1. To collect warnings from the service, i.e., in general case, the function calls stack of arbitrary depth. It actually looks more like a general programming problem than a NestJS thing
2. But even when one implement the feature from the first paragraph the NestJS will walk along the GraphQL graph by itself and there can be additional logs in nested fields.

The solution in its complete general form probably will be over-complicated but at least can anyone suggest the good design for the case represented by the example code?

I have a couple of thoughts:

1. Should every function in the service return its warnings alongside its main response (for example, in a tuple) so we can incrementally "fold" the array of warnings while "unfolding" the calls stack?
2. Maybe it would be better to implement using some decorator by which we will mark our service methods?
3. Maybe RxJS – the NestJS beloved one – can offer us some solution? (I don't know a lot about this library/their philosophy)
4. Actually the default form of the NestJS output is already looking similar to what I want, it's a JSON with 2 root properties: "errors" and "data". And they can be automatically sent to you simultaneously if the error happened is not so fatal to proceed. Can we somehow overwrite the default response object schema and place warnings there?

The whole question is heavily inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868843) SO discussion but it unfortunately says nothing about the actual possible implementation.

Comment: errors in graphql are returned in separate `error` [response] sibling, not inside `data` ... `extensions` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've implemented a custom context factory which is executed automatically on every GraphQL request and constructs the object of desired format:

app.module.ts:

```js
export interface AppContext {
  warnings: string[];
}
const contextFactory: ContextFunction<any, AppContext> = () => ({
  warnings: []
});
```

Now we can benefit from our newly created interface to add strong typings whenever we reference the context, e.g.:

some.resolver.ts

```js
@Mutation()
async remove(
  @Args('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string,
  @Context() ctx: AppContext
): Promise<FindOneDto>
{
  return new FindOneDto(await this.service.remove(id, ctx.warnings));
}
```

Here the service can add its own warnings to the context.

To collect all of them and return to the API caller I override `formatResponse` function and append the warnings to the extensions (this is a special GraphQL meta-field serving the developing purposes):

app.module.ts:

```js
const graphqlConfig: GqlModuleOptions = {
  context: contextFactory,
  formatResponse: (
    response: GraphQLResponse | null,
    context: GraphQLRequestContext<AppContext>,
  ): GraphQLResponse =>
  {
    const warnings = context.context.warnings;
    if (warnings.length) {
      if (response) {
        const extensions = response.extensions || (response.extensions = {});
        extensions.warnings = warnings;
      } else {
        return { extensions: { warnings } };
      }
    }
    return response || {};
  },
  ...
}
```

Similar approach is used in the official Apollo extension example: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-tracing/src/index.ts.

The only drawback I see now is that injecting the context in resolver's arguments breaks the compliance with auto-generated TypeScript interfaces (I use schema-first approach). In such case, we can switch to per-request-based mode so our resolver/service class instance will be created individually for each and every new request: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes. Now we can access a context right in the methods without introducing any additional parameters. But this comes with increased latencies and, perhaps, memory-consumption. Another approach will be to create a standalone Nest interceptor.

Comment: **AGAIN! don't attach [anything] to `data`!!!** ... apollo client writes response (data) to [normalized] cache, not queried parts/props are filtered out ... you won't get `warnings` in e.g. `useQuery` `data` [result] prop

Comment: @xadm yikes. Currently I see my new attached property (at least in the GraphQL Playground). Well, then my only option left is to implement a GraphQL wrapper to the response body... For the schema-first approach this will be very verbose...

Comment: read again https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Data ... if error then 'data' MUST be `null` ...  usable in playground, UNUSABLE in apollo, the most popular graphql client, really? ... not usable at app level code ... **warnings (like logs and other debug/profiling data) should be attached to `error`**... and of course should be configurable (off on production) ... TS is out of this academic discussion, **warnings or errors are not a part of data [shape] at least in graphql**

Comment: OK, I canceled my answer and added a note, thanks

Comment: @xadm I've completely rewrite my answer based on your suggestions

Comment: IMHO service doesn't require context injection, it can just return warnings within the response (legal here, not legal for entire graphql response) ... it can/needs to be collected in resolver into context ... in resolver: 1: `res=await someService()`, 2. copy warnings `context.warnings[]=res.warnings`, 3. `return res` ... and nothing more (doesn't require removing) as **additional resolver returned elements** (not matching requested props/tree) **are filtered out from the response** (tree) before return - this ability is sometimes used to pass arbitrary data between parent and child resolver

Comment: @xadm OK, got it, maybe it's "cleaner" solution not to expose the context things to the service. Just a single question, `formatResponse` function is remaining the same in this case, right?

Comment: @xadm oh, I see, but my complaint was about the resolver signature, not service. For example, Nest generates the following: `export interface IMutation { update(id: string, data: UpdateInput) ...` and I would like to use it in the resolver definition: `export class Resolver implements Partial<gqlSchema.IQuery>, Partial<gqlSchema.IMutation> { ...`, but now my `update()` implementation also contains `ctx` argument so it messing with the `IMutation`

Comment: IDK nest.js but I don't think it's the proper way to create middleware, you probably should attach an array to GqlExecutionContext, use @Injectable... sth like that

Comment: @xadm seems like you're right with that, too, sir :) In default, normal configuration we cannot access the context unless we explicitly inject it to the resolver's method. But we can switch to the per-request-based mode when the service class instance will be created individually for each and every new request: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes. And then we can access the context more easily. But this comes with increased latencies and, perhaps, memory-consumption

Comment: And same is applied for the resolver as well, we can switch it to the per-request base too, as we decide earlier to not expose the request-related things to the service

Comment: per request is [usually] required for auth